# glassfish no start GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.system.proxy' is not installed

Tags: linux, glassfish, debian

I im using glassfish 2.1 with openjdk 7, debian 7 amd64. Glassfish no start, show  glassfish no start GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.system.proxy' is not installed, any ideas???

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to install `gsettings-desktop-schemas`.

Answer (score 4):

Or alternatively, try this

```
sudo /usr/bin/glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

With archlinux, this solution worked to address this bug

```
(gedit:22225): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 09:49:08.734: Settings schema 'org.gnome.gedit.plugins.spell' is not installed
```

I found the solution there:

- [Error: GLib-GIO-ERROR: Settings schema 'org.blueman.general' is not installed · Issue #274 · blueman-project/blueman](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/274)
- [mate-screenshot GLib-GIO-ERROR - schema not installed / Applications & Desktop Environments / Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=165030)